# How to enable auto reset in Arduino Leonardo?

Tags: reset, bootloader, atmega32u4

I am  trying to program an ATMega32u4 microcontroller through arduino IDE. I have added external oscillator(16Mhz) and capacitors and few other connections according to the Schematic. I had put a sparkfun bootloader onto it(caterina) using Avr Pocket Programmer. A usb 2.0 is connected to the microcontroller. Arduino IDE recognizes microcontroller as Arduino Leonardo with the help of this usb. [Bootloader file](https://github.com/sparkfun/SF32u4_boards/tree/master/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/caterina).

I was able to upload codes into the microcontroller but the issue is, I have to put the reset pin to ground momentarily each time when the IDE goes to uploading stage. 
If i do not reset it, the COM Port for leonardo disappears but it never comes back until I reset it manually and therefore the uploading bar just gets stuck. I have also added the circuit connected to the Reset Pin according to the schematic but even if i remove all of it and just connect a switch, no difference can be observed. No power on reset is working.

Since one can upload codes without having to manually reset each time in Arduino Leonardo, I was wondering what could be the issue here.

Is there a way to auto reset this? Or perhaps fix the auto reset issue in this case? [image]

Comment: how is it done on rhe Leonardo?

Comment: How is what done on the leonardo? I'm sorry, I didn't get your question.

Comment: did you look at the Leonardo schematic?

Comment: Yes, I did. Also rigged the circuit connected to the reset pin but it doesn't seem to be working. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: The leonardo should reset if you open the serial port at 1200 baud then close it again. If there is no serial port showing then your sketch isn't creating one, or your sketch isn't running properly.

Comment: Yes, I did try that and it works. However, I would need to do that while uploading the code quickly, else the code won't upload. Again, it's not exactly an automated thing.